# How to accomplish case insensitive buffer search and case sensitive completion?

Tags: vim

I like to use strict mode. When I am typing lower case variable (e.g. "path") and press `<C-N>` I do not want to see constants or class names with this prefix (e.g. "PATH_TO_ROOT" or "PathGenerator"). Also, constants are usually at the top of completion and I have to press extra keys. That is why I have disabled `ignorecase` option. On the other hand, I almost newer pay attention to case when I am searching the buffer. As far as I know there is no dedicated option for searching or insert completion. I can place `\c` in the pattern, but again it requires extra keystrokes each time. Okay we can use mapping:

```
cnoremap <expr><CR> getcmdtype() =~ "[/?]" && getcmdline() !~ '\\c$' ? "\<End>\\c\<CR>" : "\<CR>"
```

But this reduces readability a little bit. I am wonder is there a better solution? A dedicated option I am not aware of? Following options are also declined:

Setting the option when entering command line mode and disabling when entering insert mode. This will cause to redraw the screen if there are highlighted matches from previous search. Highlighted `Foo` and `FOO` will be disappeared when entering insert mode and will be highlighted again when entering command line mode.

Setting `@/` register.

```
cnoremap <expr><CR> getcmdtype() =~ "[/?]" ? "\<Esc>:set @/ = histget("search")" : "\<CR>"
```

1. It is not working in visual mode (correct me if I am wrong).
2. It also does only forward searching.

**The question**

How to do case sensitive insert (cmd-line) completion with `ignorecase` set, or how to do case insensitive search when `ignorecase` is not set.

**Requirements**

1. It works both in visual/normal mode.
2. Forward/bakward search.
3. The pattern is present in history.

Please keep in mind the solution must be simple. I would rather do case sensitive search all the time than keeping a plugin for searching.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just KISS it?

```
noremap / /\c
noremap ? ?\c
```

Yes, it only saves two keystrokes.

Comment: You should at least add 2 more lines for visual mode. And it is possible there are other ways to enter search mode. The main reason - it reduces readability. Placing `\c` at the end of the search pattern is a better but not ideal.

Comment: @Evgeniy `noremap` works for normal, visual and operator pending mode. So even `d/pattern` will work without problems. Where to place `\c` is the matter of taste. Personally, I like it at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I always use nnoremap so I did not even notice that you omitted "n".